# android: getting an error in using spannable string in android

Tags: android

I'm new to android.I want my text color should change after some second or half so i have used `counDownTimer` and `spannableString` to perform. Its working properly for the first time.but i want to restart this operation again of button click but I'm receiving an error.

```
private void textAnimation() 
    {
        final String str[] = tvPrayer.getText().toString().split(" ");
        long totalTime = (str.length + 2) * 500;
        Log.i(TAG, "totalTime: " + totalTime);

        timer = new CountDownTimer(totalTime, 500)
        {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
            {
                Log.i(TAG, "In side Tick");
                String val = str[counter++];
                Log.i(TAG, "val is :" + val);

                spannableString = new SpannableString(tvPrayer.getText().toString());
                lastIndex = indexOf+ val.length();
                Log.i(TAG, "start index :"+ indexOf);
                Log.i(TAG, "last index :" + lastIndex);
                spannableString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#FFA500")),0,lastIndex, 0);
                indexOf =0;
                indexOf = lastIndex+1;
                tvPrayer.setText(spannableString);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish()
            {
                timer.cancel();
            }
        };
    }
```

Onbutton click, I have just restart.

Here is my logcat.

```
12-18 14:55:31.949: E/AndroidRuntime(9804): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-18 14:55:31.949: E/AndroidRuntime(9804): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (0 ... 233) ends beyond length 229
12-18 14:55:31.949: E/AndroidRuntime(9804):     at android.text.SpannableStringInternal.checkRange(SpannableStringInternal.java:349)
12-18 14:55:31.949: E/AndroidRuntime(9804):     at android.text.SpannableStringInternal.setSpan(SpannableStringInternal.java:77)
12-18 14:55:31.949: E/AndroidRuntime(9804):     at android.text.SpannableString.setSpan(SpannableString.java:46)
12-18 14:55:31.949: E/AndroidRuntime(9804):     at com.mindbowser.fragments.Practice4BPrayerFragment$1.onTick(Practice4BPrayerFragment.java:129)
12-18 14:55:31.949: E/AndroidRuntime(9804):     at android.os.CountDownTimer$1.handleMessage(CountDownTimer.java:124)
12-18 14:55:31.949: E/AndroidRuntime(9804):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-18 14:55:31.949: E/AndroidRuntime(9804):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-18 14:55:31.949: E/AndroidRuntime(9804):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
12-18 14:55:31.949: E/AndroidRuntime(9804):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-18 14:55:31.949: E/AndroidRuntime(9804):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-18 14:55:31.949: E/AndroidRuntime(9804):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-18 14:55:31.949: E/AndroidRuntime(9804):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-18 14:55:31.949: E/AndroidRuntime(9804):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)d the timer.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
12-18 14:55:31.949: E/AndroidRuntime(9804): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (0 ... 233) ends beyond length 229
```

Its clear that your `spannableString`'s length is 229, while you are trying to call setSpan using lastIndex as 233.

Issue is with `lastIndex`

```
lastIndex = indexOf+ val.length();
```

Here, indexOf is changed like this when you call this function for first time:

```
indexOf = lastIndex+1;
```

(First time this worked as first time, `indexOf` was 0.)

This is increasing your `lastIndex` beyond the length of actual string.

If you want to set span for text after last changed text, then use `indexOf` in `startIndex`. Don't add it to `lastIndex`.

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation says:

`public abstract void setSpan (Object what, int start, int end, int flags)`:

> Attach the specified markup object to the range `start…end` of the text,
>   or move the object to that range if it was already attached elsewhere.

In your case, **the text** means `tvPrayer.getText().toString()` from `spannableString = new SpannableString(tvPrayer.getText().toString())`.

So, do you think `0,lastIndex` is always the right beginning position and ending position of `tvPrayer.getText().toString()`?